# How to search multiple command output in linux mint

Tags: linux

I am running multiple commands in single line and need to search the pattern
ex:

```
cd udaya/;service status;service2 status
```

after i want to  search some pattern through grep in that same line only for those two services instead of

```
cd udaya/;service status | grep -i  'text';service2 status | grep -i 'text'
```

Why because i want to search same pattern from these two srvices.

So , i can see only the pattern output from those services.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about using subshells?

```
( service status & service2 status ) | grep -i 'text'
```

Alternatively, you could go for [named pipes](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20named%20pipes).

Comment: Possibly `&&` or `;` would be better there given that we don't know whether running `service2` is dependent on `service` having already completed...

Comment: Well, yes, it depends on that. But if they both need to run in parallel, it's just &.